# Starting CSS animation when element is beeing displayed

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-animations

I'm trying to animate some elements with CSS animation and keyframes when they are beeing displayed:

```css
-webkit-animation: stamp 600ms ease-in-out 1;
   -moz-animation: stamp 600ms ease-in-out 1;
        animation: stamp 600ms ease-in-out 1;
```

If I toggle the visibility via display:block/none; the animation is beeing played nicely from the beginning in Chrome and modern IE but not in Firefox (didn't test in Safari).

Is there a way I can achieve this in Firefox just as well?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8aDq/2/) I created for testing.

Comment: `-moz-opacity`? Really? Firefox didn’t support animations in the last version that was necessary… same with `-moz-border-radius`. Unprefix! I’m also not sure whether `-webkit-opacity` ever existed, but if it did, you really don’t need it now.

Comment: @minitech: thanks for the hint! I just checked caniuse.com and there definitely is no vendor prefix for opacity and border-radius. Wow, I was using this for quite a long time now and apparently never checked back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `.hidden` after `.badge` and remove the animations:

```css
.hidden {
    animation: none;
    display: none;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rninty/y8aDq/4/)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick if I use an additional class (.hidden). I wonder if this is also possible without an additional class by just showing and hiding the elements using the jQuery functions show() and hide(). This is actually what I got in my project and I was happy that Chrome and IE play the animations everytime. I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8aDq/5/) using the function .toggle() which corresponds more with my problem. However I marked this answer as accepted, because it is the answer to my (wrong) fiddle. But if there's a hint to my actual problem I'd be happy :)

Comment: @RalfHeumann: I don’t think so, unfortunately. `.toogle().toggleClass('hidden')` isn’t *too* bad, though, is it?